# Managing a collection of vectors of templated derived types

Tags: c++, generics, boost, metaprogramming

**The X: What I want to do:**

I have the types: `BaseType` and `DerivedType<int k>` (see code below), and I need to handle a collection of `K` vectors of the derived types `std::vector<DerivedType<k>>`, `k = 1...K`. I'd like to access the objects in these vectors, and perform an operation on them that depends on `k`. `K` is a compile time constant. The problem is illustrated in the implementation:

The types are defined as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct BaseType { // Interface of the DerivedTypes
  virtual void print(){std::cout << "BaseType!" << std::endl; }
};

template< int k >
struct DerivedType : public BaseType {
  static const int k_ = k;
  // ... function calls templated on k ...
  void print(){std::cout << "DerivedType: " << k_ << std::endl;}
};

template< int k >
void doSomething ( DerivedType<k>& object ) { object.print(); }
```

And what I want to do is:

```
int main() {

  // My collection of vectors of the derived types:
  std::vector<DerivedType<0>> derType0(2);
  std::vector<DerivedType<1>> derType1(1);
  std::vector<DerivedType<2>> derType2(3);
  // ... should go to K: std::vector<DerivedType<K>> derTypeK;

  // Iterate over the derived objects applying a k-dependent templated function:
  std::for_each(begin(derType0),end(derType0),[](DerivedType<0>& object){
    doSomething<0>(object);
  });
  std::for_each(begin(derType1),end(derType1),[](DerivedType<1>& object){
    doSomething<1>(object);
  });
  std::for_each(begin(derType2),end(derType2),[](DerivedType<2>& object){
    doSomething<2>(object);
  });

  return 0;
}
```

I want to avoid repeating code, such that I only have to change `K`, which is a compile time constant of `O(10)`. Ideally, I would have something "more like" this:

```
// Pseudocode: do not try to compile this

create_derived_objects(DerivedType,K)
  = std::vector< std::vector<DerivedType<k>>* > my_K_derived_types;                                                  

for each vector<DerivedType<k>>* derivedTypes in my my_K_derived_types
  for each object in (*derivedTypes)
    doSomething<k> on object of type derivedType<k>
    // I could also restrict doSomething<k> to the base interface
```

Each vector of derived types contains `O(10^6)` to `O(10^9)` objects. The inner-most loops are the most time consuming part of my application making dynamic_cast only an option for the outer-most loop.

**The Y: what I have tryed without succes.**

I am at the moment studying the Abrahams C++ Template Metaprogramming book to see if I could use `boost::mpl`. I am also doing the tutorials on `boost::fusion` to see if I could use it too. However, the learning curve of these libraries is rather large, so I wanted to ask first before I invest a week in something when a better and simpler solution is available.

My first try was to wrapp my vectors `std::vector<DerivedType<k>>` such that I can create a `vector<WrappedDerivedTypes*>`, and access each of the single vectors separately within a `for_each` loop. However, in the loop I have a series of `if(dynamic_cast<std::vector<DerivedType<0>>>(WrappedVector) != 0 ){ do for_each loop for the derived objects } else if( dynamic_cast...) { do...} ...` that I wasn't able to eliminate.

Comment: Can your `doSomething` function just take a reference to `BaseType`?  The implementation you show does not depend on the `k` template parameter.

Comment: Further to what quamrana suggests: why not just make `doSomething()` a virtual method, and explicitly specialise it for each derived type?  Then you could just store your k vectors in a vector-of-vectors of pointer-to`BaseType`.  (You would need a "factory method" to construct each `DerivedType<k>` object initially, but thereafter they can be treated uniformly via the parent `BaseType` type.)  As it stands, I don't see what is gained by making `DerivedType<k>` derive from `BaseType`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a recursive solution based on a generic linked list of vectors, a strategy pattern and a thing that applies strategies recursively through the linked list? (**note**: see the improved version at the end):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <int j>
class holder {
public:
    const static int k = j;
};

template <int j>
class strategy {
public:
    void operator()(holder<j> t)
    {
        std::cout << "Strategy " << t.k << std::endl;
    }
};

template <int k>
class lin_vector {
private:
    std::vector<holder<k>> vec;
    lin_vector<k-1> pred;
public:
    lin_vector(const lin_vector<k-1> &pred, std::vector<holder<k>> vec)
        : vec(vec), pred(pred) { }
    std::vector<holder<k>> get_vec() { return vec; }
    lin_vector<k-1> &get_pred() { return pred; }
};

template <>
class lin_vector<0> {
public:
    lin_vector() { }
};

template <int k, template <int> class strategy>
class apply_strategy {
public:
    void operator()(lin_vector<k> lin);
};

template <int k, template <int> class strategy>
void apply_strategy<k, strategy>::operator()(lin_vector<k> lin)
{
    apply_strategy<k-1, strategy>()(lin.get_pred());
    for (auto i : lin.get_vec())
    strategy<k>()(i);
}

template <template <int> class strategy>
class apply_strategy<0, strategy>
{
public:
    void operator()(lin_vector<0> lin) { /* does nothing */ } 
};


template <int k>
lin_vector<k> build_lin()
{
    return lin_vector<k>(build_lin<k-1>(), {holder<k>()});
}

template <>
lin_vector<0> build_lin()
{
    return lin_vector<0>();
}

int main(void)
{
    apply_strategy<5, strategy>()(build_lin<5>());
}
```

Compile it with a C++11 compiler.
Most probably you'll find unsatisfactory the fact that building a `lin_vector` requires a lot of copying, but you can specialize the structure to suit your needs (perhaps substituting the `pred` with a pointer or embedding the creation strategy straight into the linked list).

**EDIT**: here there is an improved version which avoids a lot of copying and handles list building and processing in a more coherent and uniform way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <int j>
class holder {
public:
    const static int k = j;
};

template <int k>
class lin_vector {
private:
    std::vector<holder<k>> vec;
    lin_vector<k-1> pred;
public:
    std::vector<holder<k>> &get_vec() { return vec; }
    lin_vector<k-1> &get_pred() { return pred; }
};

template <>
class lin_vector<0> {
public:
    lin_vector() { }
};

template <int k, template <int> class strategy>
class apply_strategy {
public:
    void operator()(lin_vector<k> &lin);
};

template <int k, template <int> class strategy>
void apply_strategy<k, strategy>::operator()(lin_vector<k> &lin)
{
    apply_strategy<k-1, strategy>()(lin.get_pred());
    strategy<k>()(lin.get_vec());
}

template <template <int> class strategy>
class apply_strategy<0, strategy>
{
public:
    void operator()(lin_vector<0> &lin) { /* does nothing */ } 
};

template <int j>
class strategy {
public:
    void operator()(std::vector<holder<j>> &t)
    {
        std::cout << "Strategy " << j << ", elements: ";
        for (auto v : t)
            std::cout << v.k << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

template <int j>
class build_strategy {
public:
    void operator()(std::vector<holder<j>> &t)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < j; i++)
            t.push_back(holder<j>());
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    const int K = 5;
    lin_vector<K> list;
    apply_strategy<K, build_strategy>()(list);
    apply_strategy<K, strategy>()(list);
}
```

Comment: This basic design could be improved up a little, especially about the `lin_list` thing. A good idea could be to leave default-inizialized the vector and then fill the vectors using the `apply_strategy` idea. In this way you'll end up with a generic structure which is easily constructed (just write `lin_lis<k> l` and you are fine) and which is independent on the policy used to fill the vectors.

Comment: Wow! Really nice answer! Thank you a lot ! In order to avoid copying the vectors around I've changed the linked list of vectors into a linked list of vector pointers. That way only the vector pointers need to be copied. What do you mean by substituting the pred with a pointer? As far as I understood, pred contains the previous node (with his corresponding vector, or vector pointer). Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. BTW, I think the new version is better: basically a lin_list<K> is a linked list of empty vectors, and then you fill the vectors by defining a policy. No copying needed at all, your building policy is neatly enclosed and you can stack-allocate everything.

Comment: I am going to look into filling the vectors now with the apply strategy idea. Using different filling policies would be awesome. Really thanks again! Any tips into what to read to be able to come up with a solution like this myself? I just finished design patterns but I feel that in c++ my biggest barrier is the language itself (unlike in python).

Comment: I'm not really an expert of template programming, but I find the classic of Alexandrescu mind-blowing at that: http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Design-Generic-Programming-Patterns/dp/0201704315

Answer (score 1):

A solution free of virtual dispatch is possible, though it's probably overkill.

The first thing you need is a function template `doSomething<K>()` that you specialise on each derived type:

```
template <int K>
void doSomething(vector<DerivedType<K> >& x);

template <>
void doSomething<1>(vector<DerivedType<1> >& x) { ... }

template <>
void doSomething<2>(vector<DerivedType<2> >& x) { ... }   // etc.
```

You could then build a strongly-typed collection of vectors using a recursively defined `struct` template:

```
template <int K>
struct vov {
    vov<K - 1> prev;
    vector<DerivedType<K> > v;
};

template <>
struct vov<1> {
    vector<DerivedType<1> > v;
};
```

Finally, you can write a recursive function template to process this structure:

```
template <int K>
void process(vov<K>& x) {
    doSomething(x.v);     // Type inference will find the right doSomething()
    process(x.prev);      // Here too
}

template <>
void process<1>(vov<1>& x) {
    doSomething(x.v);
}
```

Now the main code will look like:

```
vov<42> foo;
process(foo);
```

Because the `process()` function call performs iteration through the use of recursion, it will probably use K stack frames unnecessarily; however it is tail recursion, which modern optimising C++ compilers can usually convert into plain iteration with no stack wastage.  Using tail recursion forces us to process the vectors in "reverse" order, so that the `DerivedType<1>` vector is processed last, but if necessary this could be fixed with a slightly more elaborate template using 2 `int` template parameters (one will "count up" towards the other, instead of a single `int` parameter that "counts down" towards 1).

**Observe that there is no benefit gained by deriving each `DerivedType<k>` from `BaseType` in this solution -- you may as well forget about `BaseType` altogether, unless you need it for a different reason.**

There may well be MPL primitives that simplify some of these processes -- if anyone knows them, please feel free to edit.